# I'm not able to login to hackerrank.com website from my Windows 10 Laptop as the page isn't loading

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, browser-cache

[hackerrank website on my laptop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7M0MI.png)

None of the login buttons are actually working.
Here are some console errors if it helps: [Developer tools console errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIF7s.png)

Now I am not able to find any solution to this even after doing google search on my part.
Things that I tried so far:

- Cleared all the cache/cookies and browsing history
- Did dnaflush from cmd
- Tried to do this steps in a different browser also (i.e. Microsoft edge), but still same issue persists.

It would be great if anybody can help me out here a bit.
Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You should connect via SSL. Change in the URL the protocoll from http:// to https:// or just use my link here: https://www.hackerrank.com/auth/login

Then you should get a better website. If it still does not work, turn off your adblocker - alt least during the login process.

Comment: Hello @Boba Fit, I was accessing the website via https only. The link that you've given given is the same giving me same issue. Also I don't have any adblocker installed in chrome extensions. And on top of it, this is the same issue in Microsoft edge, so really don't know what's happening here : /

Comment: Using the link solved the problem I was also having. I am using Opera, but I don't think it matters.